# Create a zip file from a list of selected files and make the zipped file downloadable

Tags: 7, files

I have a list of image files. I need to archive those files in zip format and make the archived file downloadable. I have seen `ArchiverZip` class defined in the `system module` of **Drupal 7**. But I couldn't be able to create a *zip* file. How can I do this in **Drupal 7** ? Is there any `hooks` or custom `modules` for this ? Please help me out with this.

**UPDATED**
Following are the codes:

```
$zip = new ArchiverZip('archive.zip');
foreach($_POST['img'] as $fid):
    $query = db_select('file_managed', 'fn')
            ->condition('fid', $fid)
            ->fields('fn', array('filename'));
    $result = $query->execute();

    foreach($result as $row) {
        if(file_exists('sites/default/files/'.$row->filename)){
            var_dump($zip->add($base_path.'sites/default/files/'.$row->filename));
        }
    }
 endforeach;
```

And this reflects the following error

> *Exception*: Cannot open archive.zip in *ArchiverZip->__construct()* (line *91* of *basepath\modules\system\system.archiver.inc*).

Please help me with this . .

Comment: What problems were you having with the ArchiverZip class? It seems like a pretty straight forward class to me (though I haven't used it)

Comment: @2pha please check the updated content . .

Comment: Try including the ZIP class to your function `module_load_include('inc', 'zip_archive', 'zip_archive.class');`

Comment: @NikhilM nope . . still not working mate . .

Comment: Please check Drupal log to see if there is any clue. also check archive.zip permissions.

Comment: check this http://drupal.org/node/83253

Comment: @NikhilM thanks mate . . i forgot to create the zip file . . now working fine . . :))

Comment: How can I do it in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you include the class

```
module_load_include('inc', 'zip_archive', 'zip_archive.class');
```

Also check permissions for `archive.zip` file. Create one if its not there.

Comment: There is one thing need to ask you more buddy . . How can i arrange all the files in the same folder as files inside the zipped file are located like archive.zip\sites\default\files\

Comment: I need to arrange the files like archive.zip\

Comment: Add the files to zip folder as they exists in the disk.

Comment: I don't get you . . Will you explain more please ? ?

Comment: I think you want the zip file with files exactly in your disk right ? if yes just add the files to zip as they are in disk. `-r`

Comment: I guess you didn't get what i am trying to say . . Please go through the structure . . I need to have the files structured in the zip file like archive.zip\a.jpg, archive.zip\b.jpg and so on unlike archive.zip\sites\default\files\a.jpg, archive.zip\sites\default\files\b.jpg . . Hope you got me now . . Please help me with this structure . .

Comment: ok got it, and sorry i cant find any straight way. I would do it like copy the files to a temp folder and zip the temp folder and unlink the temp folder. this should work. give it a try. let me know if you find a better way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7965/discussion-between-coosal-and-nikhil-m)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the accepted answer is correct. You don't need to include the class. To get this to work, you need to make sure that the file you are passing the ZipArchiver constructor already exists - that is where I believe the original question was getting the error:

> Exception: Cannot open archive.zip

To make sure the file you are passing to the constructor already exists, try this (assuming the drupal path is something like a private or temp directory)

```
$filename = [drupal path] . [zip file name];
fopen(drupal_realpath($filename), 'w');
$zip = new ArchiverZip(drupal_realpath($filename));
```

We pass the path to `drupal_realpath()` so it converts the path from something like `"private://filename"` to `"[my app]/sites/default/files/private/filename"`.